# How to draw the circle with certain radius around the point in the plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to draw the bubble plot with additional central point. 
X1, Y1 is the x-axis and y-axis, respectively, and N1 is the radius of the circle around the point.

```r
require(ggplot2)
df <- structure(list(X1 = c(1:10), 
                     Y1 = c(15:24), 
                     N1 = c(5, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 1)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
df
   X1 Y1 N1
1   1 15  5
2   2 16  2
3   3 17  3
4   4 18  5
5   5 19  1
6   6 20  2
7   7 21  6
8   8 22  3
9   9 23  4
10 10 24  1
```

Simply, I thought that it will be okay to overlap the bubble plot and basic plot.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=X1, y=Y1, size=N1))+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_point(alpha=0.3, color='blue')+
  scale_size(range=c(10,40))+
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

But there were two problems.

1. How can I eliminate the line around the circles?
2. How can I add the center point on the bubble plot?

The below figure is the expected result.
[image]

I tried to mimic the code in this site: https://datavizpyr.com/how-to-add-circles-around-specific-data-points-in-r/, but the last line overlapped the previous result.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x=X1, y=Y1, size=N1))+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_point(alpha=0.3, color='blue')+
  scale_size(range=c(10,40))+
  geom_point(df, mapping=aes(x=X1, y=Y1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember, aesthetics are by default inherited from the base `ggplot()` call to all subsequent layers, so the small central dots were inheriting the `size` aesthetic. Use the `size` aesthetic only in the `aes` call to the "bubble" layer.

To get rid of the lines around the circles, you can change the points to `shape = 21`, which is a filled circle. That way, you can set the `fill` colour to blue and make the line `colour` completely transparent.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = X1, y = Y1))+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_point(aes(size = N1), shape = 21, alpha = 0.3, fill ='blue',
             color = alpha("white", 0)) +
  scale_size(range = c(10, 40)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]